# Loading screen while javascript function executes

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have following javascript code which loads information from multiple json files and appends them in HTML table if "info" parameter in URL is true.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var appList=["app1","app2","app3"];

    //function to get url parameters
    var parameters = new URL(window.location).searchParams;
    var info=parameters.get('info');

    if (info=="true"){
        for (var i=0;i<appList.length;i++){
            setInfoAndDateUtil(app)
        }
    }   

    function setInfoAndDateUtil(app){
        $.ajax({ 
            url:'server_name/'+ app + '/info.json'; 
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType:'application/json',  
            success: function(jsonData){
                var info=jsonData.info;
                td=$("#" + app);
                td.text(info).css("text-align", "center");
            }
        })
    }
```

The ajax requests are taking some time since they are loading about 16 json files. So I want to add loading screen  while this function executes.

I have tried few methods like this but none of them are working.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $("#wait").css("display", "none");
});
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach using JQuery:

```
// Add Loader on ajax calls
$("body").prepend("<div id='spinner'><img src='/images/spinner.gif'></div>");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
  $('#spinner').show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
   $('#spinner').hide();
});
```

Comment: I am getting following error doing this `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).once is not a function`

Comment: I edited my answer check it now, and also keep in mind that you should have an image to that /images path